# Add class on OWL Carousel afterLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, owl-carousel

I'm using [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing), trying to add class `.border-red` to `<div class="item">` after lazyLoad, means call this function after lazyLoad `afterLazyLoad`

*Example*: `$(".item").addClass("border-red");` when lazy loaded. Means add class function execute after OWLCarousel lazyLoaded.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
items : 4,
lazyLoad : true,
navigation : true
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
</div>
```

Here is OWLCarousel [Options and Callbacks](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing)

OWLCarousel [demo](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html) >

How to addclass function execute after OWLCarousel lazyLoaded?

Comment: You need to set `afterLazyLoad` to `true`, in your options, just as you did with `lazyLoad` and `navigation`. You ought to be able to access the callback function with this option update.

Comment: @TylerSloan Hi, thanks, but how access the callback function ?

Comment: @vijayP's answer is good.

Comment: your demo link goes to a sp@m site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      items : 4,
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : true,
      afterLazyLoad: function(elem){
          $(elem).addClass("border-red");
      }
   });

});
```

Here `afterLazyLoad` is a callback function

Comment: just saw the implementation of owl carousel. Did small change in above code. Could you please try one more time with this newer code?

Comment: Hi it works, but Progress Bar has gone, mean Progress Bar not showing, Here is demo of Progress Bar:  http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/progressBar.html

Comment: must be some CSS positioning issue. may be progress bar is getting overlapped by your red border. Can you please take a look at that.

Comment: I have seen HTML Source by InspectElement but Progress Bar not there. Progress Bar call function not working if is use your given JS.

Comment: oh..this is strange. This is the supported way and `afterLazyLoad` callback is valid callback function as per their documentation. So if its not working with progress bar; it means that there is a bug in their library code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90906/discussion-between-aabira-and-vijayp).

Comment: sorry @Aabira. Yesterday I left for the day so couldn't able to ping you back. Still you are facing the issue?